# How do you either remove or set the character limit of a field in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a field that has a character limit set to 20, but I can't figure out how to remove it or set it to something higher.

Answer (score 1):

This will be retrieved from then database. Why do you want to change it ?
If you changed the size of the field in the database and you want to update it inside the report use "Verify database".

Comment: Because the input in the software's database that it's pulling from doesn't have any limit. So I'm not sure why it's even adding that limit.

Comment: Is the field pointing to the database or to a formula or SQLExpression ?

Comment: We talked with our software company that uses this crystal report, and they verified that there is a software enforced character limit set that we cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the left formula in string function in crystal reports and limit the  field value to certain characters.

```
Left({TableName},25)
```

will show the first 25 characters.

Either goes for right formula as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in crystal report there is no limitation on number of characters you can just expand the field. If it is in database nothing can be done at crystal report. You need to change at database level.

Comment: We talked with our software company that uses this crystal report, and they verified that there is a software enforced character limit set that we cannot change.